# How to ucomment [<!-- .* -->] this pattern using shell script?

Tags: shell, sed

```
 <!--  <Con xlink:href="abcd.sh"/>-->
```

I want to uncomment above line using bash script.

**I want the below output :**

```
<Con xlink:href="abcd.sh"/>
```

**I tried below command but, its not working.**

```
sed -i '/abcd.sh/s/^<!--//g' $filename2
```

Comment: How about  `sed -i '/abcd.sh/s/^<!--\s*//;s/\s*-->$//' $filename2`?

Comment: last part(-->)this removed, but first part(<!--) still in place

Comment: There is, I think, an extra space at the beginning of the line. So you have to go with `sed -i '/abcd.sh/s/^\s*<!--\s*//;s/\s*-->\s*$//' $filename2`

Answer (score 0):

Use the method I say, I hope it helps

Delete the first 6 characters of the line. (`-n 2p` means line 2 )

```
sed -n 2p filename | cut -c6
```

Delete the last 6 characters of the line

```
sed -n 2p filename | rev | cut -c6- | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the middle part.

```
sed -i '/abcd.sh/s/<!--\(.*\)-->/\1/' $filename2
```

Also there seems to be a space before `<!--` so don't `^<`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. first remove the front `<!--`  with `sed -i 's/<!--\s*//g' filename`
2. then, remove the end `-->` with `sed -i 's/-->//g' filename`

Explanation of the first command:

- the flag `-i` tells `sed` to substitute in-place (in the same file).
- `s/<--\s*//` means: find the pattern `<--`, optionally followed by any spaces, and replace it with the empty string.
- `g` at the end, tells `sed` to do it for every match in a line.

The second command has a similar meaning.